# Jackson strips leading underscore

Tags: jackson, swagger-codegen

Our swagger specification defines a property **_links**.

```
places-result:
  type: object
  properties:
    _links:
      $ref: "#/components/schemas/links-underscore-type"
```

Using *swagger-codegen*, we see this name end up in the output class:

```
@JsonProperty("_links")
private LinksUnderscoreType _links = null;

@Schema(
    description = ""
)
@Valid
public LinksUnderscoreType getLinks() {
    return this._links;
}
```

However, Jackson adds a property with and without the leading underscore:

```
{
  "result": {
    "links": {
        "self": "http://localhost:8083/places?page=181",
        "previous": "http://localhost:8083/places?page=180",
        "first": "http://localhost:8083/places?page=0"
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": "http://localhost:8083/places?page=181",
        "previous": "http://localhost:8083/places?page=180",
        "first": "http://localhost:8083/places?page=0"
    }
}
```

As it is a Spring Boot application, we should be able to influence the naming strategy using this property:

```
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy: LOWER_CASE
```

None of the accepted values seems to preserve the specified property name.

How can we preserve the leading underscore?

Comment: If the json file you posted is the result of the serialization is it obtained by a jackson `ObjectMapper` or swagger is involved in some way ?

Comment: Swagger is only involved in the code generation, which seems to be correct. ObjectMapper is the one provided by the Spring Boot application.

Comment: Unable to reproduce,  just one question : seeing the json structure it reminds me of spring hateoas, it is unrelated to your project ?

Comment: @dariosicily My suspicion is that the non-underscored version (which has to go) is introduced by the getter method. I added that to the code snippet above. Unfortunately, as this code is generated, it would be hard to override that. I was wondering if I can configure the ObjectMapper to ignore getters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the non-underscore property came in because it was matched by the getter method. The solution is to not match the getter methods. This can be achieved in the Spring Boot config:

```
spring:
  jackson:
    mapper:
      AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS: false
```

Or in code:

```
objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS, false);
```